# Find kth smallest element in O(log n)

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

I know that if balanced, a BST height is O(log(n)), meaning searching is O(log(n)), but making an unbalanced tree into a balanced one would increase the run-time of inserting / deleting, since you would have to rebalance it after each insertion / deletion.

Is there another way to modify the BST so that I can find the Kth smallest item in O(log(n)) time, without affecting the runtime of other functions?

Comment: Since balancing the tree is amortized across multiple calls, it increases your runtime, but it does not increase your asymptotic complexity. Keeping the tree balanced is a relatively straightforward task - look RB-trees for a good example on how to do it.

Comment: http://pine.cs.yale.edu/pinewiki/OrderStatisticsTree

Comment: Why do you need an alternate for balancing? After Balancing complexity doesn't increase, so you can use balancing and then find kth smallest element in O(logn) time!

Comment: Have each node keep track of the recursive number of children it has.   That makes it easy to find the kth item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but making an unbalanced tree into a balanced one would increase the run-time of inserting /  deleting, since you would have to rebalance it after each insertion / deletion.

Not true, self-balancing binary trees also have `O(log n)` insert and delete. The basic reason is that while you do need to do rebalancing, the rebalancing itself will take a total of `O(log n)` per operation.

Have a look at [AVL trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) to get an idea of how it's able to rebalance without affecting the complexity of the operations.

Comment: Oh, so you're saying since insert is O(log(n)) and adding a rebalance function (which is O(log(n)) for a balanced tree) inside of insert makes the whole insert function equal to O(2*log(n)) which is still just O(log(n))

Comment: Sort of. The basic idea is that for something like an AVL tree, it'll basically "walk back up" the tree doing rebalances after insert. These rebalances are `O(log n)` total. But yes, it just changes the constant.